# Unable to receive URC for an incoming SMS from a modem

Tags: sms, at-command

I have an issue in being **unable to recive the URC message** from the modem whenever it **receives an SMS**.

I know that it receives them since **i can find and read them if I use AT+CMGL** but, i don't receive any notification when the modem gets them. I played around with the URC related commands but I've been unable to get it to work (other URCs work fine).

The modem is a BG600L M3 from Quectel and following is the sequence of commands i'm sending ("AT" is always omitted and the first command is literally "AT\r", basically an empty one).

```
//general config
AT\r
CFUN=1,0
E1
+QCFG=\"urc/ri/other\",\"pulse\",8,1
H0
&F
V1
+CMEE=1
&D0
E1
+CREG=2
+CGREG=2
+CEREG=2

//sms config
+CPMS=\"ME\",\"ME\",\"ME\"
+QINDCFG=\"smsincoming\",1
+CMGF=1
+CSDH=0
+CSCS=\"GSM\"
+CNMI=2,2,0,2,0

//doing some deleting and reading
+CMGD=1,3
+CPMS?

//getting the gps fix
+QGPS=1
+QGPSCFG=\"gnssconfig\",3   
+QGPSLOC=1
+QGPSEND

//resetting the gms connection
+CFUN=0
+CFUN=1,0

//setting up the gsm connection 
+QICFG=\"dataformat\",0,0
+QICFG=\"viewmode\",0
+QICFG=\"recvind\",1
+QICFG=\"tcp/retranscfg\",3,600
+QISDE=0
+QCFG=\"band\",0xf,0x80085,0x80085,1
+QCFG=\"nwscanmode\",1,1    
+QCFG=\"nwscanseq\",010101,1
+QCFG=\"iotopmode\",2,1

// checking if it's connected
+CREG?
+QNWINFO
+COPS?

//Getting the time
+CTZU=3
+CTZR=0
+QLTS
+CCLK?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set AT+CNMI=2,1,2,0,0 , that should do the trick.

According to specification ETSI TS 127 005 V11.0.0 (2012-10)

> *+CNMI: <mode>,<mt>,<bm>,<ds>,<bfr>*

by keeping <mt> value to 1 we should get indication when message is stored in ME/TA

> <mt>: integer type (the rules for storing received SMs depend on its
> data coding scheme
>
> 0 No SMS-DELIVER indications are routed to the TE.
>
> **1 If SMS-DELIVER is stored into ME/TA, indication of the memory location is routed to the TE using unsolicited result code:
> +CMTI: <mem>,<index>**

Comment: it wasn't that, tried changing that but still no urc

Answer (score 0):

Try Below command, it works for me.
AT+CNMI=2,1,0,0,0